# Execute bootm command in C

Tags: u-boot

For context, I've been adding some patches to u-boot for a project, and I already have the kernel image, device tree blob, and initrd image loaded into u-boot memory.

I've had luck in the past calling command line functions (like `do_mem_cp`) through their respective C functions, but I am not having luck with the `bootm` command. I am currently doing:

```
char *argv[4] = {"bootm", "a5001000", "b0000000", "a9000000"};
do_bootm(NULL, 0, 4, argv);
```

As I stated, this worked in the past for other commands, but during this call I'm getting the error `"Synchronous Abort" handler, esr 0x96000004`. Does anyone know of a better way to call bootm (or a similar command) from C?

Edit: This is for the Jetson TX2i

Comment: One thing I noticed is that none of the sizes of these "BLOBs" are fed into bootm... do I need to store these somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

The definition of do_bootm() is:

```
extern int do_bootm(struct cmd_tbl *cmdtp, int flag, int argc,
                    char *const argv[]);
```

In case of an error cmdtp is dereferenced to print the name of the executed command. So you should not pass NULL as cmdtp. Instead fill a structure of the appropriate type and pass a pointer to it.

Answer (score 0):

Just use run_command()

```
char cmd[1024];
snprintf(cmd, sizeof(cmd), "bootm a5001000 b0000000 a9000000");
success = run_command(cmd, 0);
```